# prestigion tablet : lost my pattern and google account and dont have recovery menu

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, tablet

i lost my android pattern and my google account password.
my tablet dont have any recovery menu and download mode ...
i hold down Vol Up + Power OR Vol Down + Power OR Home + power and ...
no resone to go in recovery menu ...
no fastboot and no adb is active ...
how i factory reset my table without adb,recovery Mode and fastboot ?
is any way to auto update from update.zip from sd card in boot time like some HTC phone ?

tablet model : Prestigio PMP5197D Ultra

help me

Answer (score 0):

You can flash your tablet to be able to use it again.
Head on this site to learn how to: [flash it](http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f906/prestigio-tablet-pmp5197d-ultra-flash-file-need-1771723/)

Comment: thanks but all flash file and method need to go setting in android and recovery menu ...
i dont have recovery...
i need method like flashtool for Xperia device ...

Comment: Did you try the instructions from here: http://www.hardreset.info/devices/prestigio/prestigio-multipad-70-ultra/

Comment: Yes But No recovery apeare ... :(